# Reset form Django with instance

Tags: django, forms, model, instance, reset

I create page to update user auth username. But in front end, if exist username django show erros (ok) but change request.user instance. So my username on menu change and input too. I need refresh page to back to normal.

```
form_profile = UserProfileForm(request.POST or None, instance = UserProfile.objects.get(user = request.user))
    form_user = UserForm(request.POST or None, instance = request.user )
    if form_profile.is_valid() and form_user.is_valid():
        form_profile.save()
        form_user.save()

    template = loader.get_template('users/user_edit.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render({"form_profile":form_profile, "form_user": form_user}, request))
```

I can't reset form with `form_profile = UserProfileForm()` because is user edit page. I need "reset" form with actual informations.

**Screenshot**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you fetch the user from the db and use that as the form instance, then `request.user` should not change.

```
user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
form_user = UserForm(request.POST or None, instance=user )
```

As an aside, it's usually recommended to redirect after a successful post request (even if you redirect to the same url). You can also use the `render` shortcut to simplify your code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def my_view(request):
    form_profile = UserProfileForm(request.POST or None, instance = UserProfile.objects.get(user = request.user))
    form_user = UserForm(request.POST or None, instance = request.user )
    if form_profile.is_valid() and form_user.is_valid():
        form_profile.save()
        form_user.save()
        return redirect('/success-url/')

    return render(request, 'users/user_edit.html', {"form_profile":form_profile, "form_user": form_user})
```

Comment: This works! About render, do the same thing, but you example is a shortcut. thanks again haha